# Graphical representation of a filtration

Tags: filtrations

I am searching for a good illustration of the concept of a filtration. So far this https://books.google.de/books?id=OBOGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA218#v=onepage&q&f=false book had a nice illustration showcasing a tree diagram for a coin toss experiment, where each coin toss can be up or down.

I am still not completely sure how to interpret it.
Is the n-th filtration the union of the sets in the n-th level of the tree?

Maybe someone could explain it to me or make an even nicer illustration showing the sets of possible realizations (in each tree node) and how I then construct the n-th filtration from this.

I am also open to an even better illustration (without a tree) which would help my understanding.

Maybe you can also find some words about why filtrations are useful. Currently, my understanding is, that filtrations are especially useful for describing the sample space $\Omega$ of stochastic experiments which are sequential in nature.

Comment: a filtration is simply an increasing sequence of $\sigma$ algebras. Generally, one thinks of them as being indexed by a time set $T$ and $\mathcal F_t$ represents the information one has up to (and including) time $t$. This heuristic interpretation is indeed correct, if $\mathcal F_t = \sigma(X_s:s\leq t)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I am aware of the formal definition but I am not yet having a picture in mind. How would I graphically come up with the increasing sequence of subsets of sigma algebras in the case of a coin tossing experiment? Let s say I start with $\mathcal{F}_1=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$, where $\Omega = \{u,d\}$, what is next $\mathcal{F}_2 =\mathcal{F}_1 \bigcup (\mathcal{F}_1 \times \Omega)$ and then $\mathcal{F}_3 =\mathcal{F}_2 \bigcup (\mathcal{F}_2 \times \Omega)$? I guess this is wrong, because I don't understand it yet fully...

Comment: The example you want to consider is meaningless. It is more useful to think of, say a random walk. $S_n = X_0+X_1+\dots+X_n$ with $X_0 = x$ almost surely and $X_i$ i.i.d $\mathrm{Unif}\{\pm 1\}$. Then consider the filtration $\mathcal F_n = \sigma(S_j:j\leq n) = \sigma(X_j:j\leq n)$

Comment: Hmm, I see how the sequence of increments determines my "past" trajectory if you want to convey this! Still I feel this picture is a bit weak. I really want to think in the sequence of sets (of increments) to fully get what a filtration means ... is this attempt foolish?

Comment: $\sigma(X_s:s\leq t)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which makes all coordinate maps $\omega\mapsto X_s(\omega)$ measurable for $s\leq t$. It is an easy exercise to show this is equal to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{x:x_{t_1}\in B_1,\dots,x_{t_n}\in B_n\}$ for $n\in \mathbb N$ and $0\leq t_1<\dots<t_n\leq t$ and $B_j$ are Borel sets. (Take the process to be real valued to avoid technicalities, if there are any)

Comment: In turn, it can then be shown that this is equal to the collection of sets of the form $\{x: x_{t_j}\in B_{t_j}\}$ where $(t_n)_n$ is a sequence of times $\leq t$. So indeed, $\sigma(X_s:s\leq t)$ gives information up to time $t$, and only up to time $t$

Comment: While I deeply appreciate your description, I look for a representation of the filtrations with (basic) sets in the form $\mathcal{F}_2= \mathcal{P}(\{0,1\}^2) = \mathcal{P}(\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1) \})$ and how these sets can be visualized with e.g. a tree diagram based generating rule. Honestly, I fail in coming up with an easy visualization/understanding how $\mathcal{F}_3$ would be generated/written down in that notation. I thought a visualization would help me... Would it be $\mathcal{F}_3= \mathcal{P}(\{0,1\}^3)$? I could understand that...